# Why is a 'semi-colon' half a colon?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

The word "semi-colon" is used for the symbol "**;**"; but this is not half of a colon "**:**": half of a colon would be a full stop "**.**". So why the usage of the term semi-colon, or *half-colon*, for a symbol part of which does not appear at all in the colon?

Comment: Take a close look at that first sentence... ;-)

Comment: *Semi*-conductor is not half a size of any conductor.

Comment: Semi doesn't mean half. It just means partly. Where are you getting this?

Comment: @Rathony conductors aren't called conductors because of their size. It's a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names 'colon' and 'semi-colon' seem more appropriate when you consider using them in a list, as in this answer from [Correct colon and semi-colon usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216093/correct-colon-and-semi-colon-usage)

> The colon correctly introduces clauses of explanation related to the first part of the preceding clause, and the semicolon separates two clauses which are related, but not joined by a coordinating conjunction, such as and.

For example, there are several reasons to use stackexchange: it contains lots of great information from helpful people; it helps to foster expertise and shared knowledge; it's free to use.

With that usage, the colon separates the 'question' from the 'answers', and the semi-colon separates the individual answers from each other while keeping them grouped together within the overall sentence. You could therefore argue that a semi-colon has half of the 'weight' of a colon, because it separates clauses from each other but not as much as a colon.

A semi-colon is also 'half' of a colon in the sense that half of it is the same as a colon. Both characters have a 'top' dot. There is a 50% similarity between : and ; so a semi-colon is 'half of a colon' plus a comma.

Comment: Could you make it more clear how this is relevant to the question regarding why the prefix "semi" is used in the name of this piece of punctuation?